# Zend Mail - bouncing mails not returning to the specified "Return-Path"

Tags: php, zend-framework, email, zend-mail

i'm working on a simple mail list app in PHP using Zend Mail. The idea is that all mail that bounce is redirected to a script which processes them and a report is generated. The script is running ok in direct tests, but I've testing it with fake mail address to test the mail list app, and it appears that the mail is not being redirected to the correct email address. Zend Mail provides the setReturnPath method to set the "Return-Path" header, it's ok to use this header for this purpose?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.additional-headers.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you're submitting your message to your mail server - mail(), calling sendmail or via SMTP, but you may want to set a 'Sender' header rather than 'Return-Path' since the return path is normally set by your local mail server, and it will use a Sender header to generate it if you provide one.